# Java Scanner - Read line breaks in to a string?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, system.in

I have a scanner that takes user input until ctrl+d and then a while loop which adds each word to a string and then prints it, but i'd like to know how to also include the new line indicators like \n in the string wherever there is a new line.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
String x = "";

while (sc.hasNext()){
  x+=sc.next() +" ";
}
System.out.println(x);
```

E.g this code would take the input:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

and print: Hello Hello Hello

Whereas I would like it to print something like:

```
Hello\n Hello\n Hello\n
```

so I can see where each line ends.

Comment: Do you want to read the entire input as one String? Then print it in a way that shows newlines as `"\n"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print "\n" so why don't you print it?

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()){
  x+=sc.nextLine() +"\n";
}
```

Comment: I'd like the loop to add the new line indicator _wherever there is a new line_, doing this will just print "\n" after every word.

Comment: so use `Scanner.nextLine` and `Scanner.hasNextLine`