# How to take input from console in java separated by comma and '\n'?

Tags: java, file-io

I want to take input from the console which is separated by the comma and next line. For eg. input is like as follow:
**1,2(next line)1,2,3(next line)2,4,6** here next line means that the next input starts from next line.
I had tried it but there are many complications, I had tried it as:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
String[] lineVector;

line = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print(line);
lineVector = (line.split('\n') || line.split(","));
int ii=2;
int m=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]);
int n=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]);
int z = n;
int[][] chuteArray = new int[m][n];
for(int i = 0;i < m;i++){
  for(int j = 0;j <n;j++){
    chuteArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(lineVector[ii]);
    ii++;
  }
}
```

But,its not working out.

Comment: Yo need to **read** the error messages you get. They're important. They matter. They tell you what is wrong, and where. Ignoring them is your main mistake. The || operator is the boolean `or` operator. It can't apply to arrays. Only to booleans. Why would you need to split a *line* with \n? There will never be a \n in a single line.

Comment: `sc.nextLine();` takes only one line. So at first it returns only `"1,2"` (without the -nextline separator). But honestly this looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What are you *really* trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Scanner - Read line breaks in to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754745/java-scanner-read-line-breaks-in-to-a-string)

Comment: You can change the output of the console messages to a text file

Comment: @OE.omergunr100 Ok, This seems a good solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanner.useDelimiter("([,\\n])");`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter("([,\\n])");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

For the input `1,2\n1,2,3\n2,4,6` this code prints

```
1
2
1
2
3
2
4
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("console.log", true));
System.setOut(stream);
```

This code changes the system console output to a file named console.log for example.